# Appendix to Transcendental Doctrine of Elements, Critique of Pure Reason

Tags: critique-of-pure-reason

Trying to encapsulate the essence of what Kant is saying here concerning the regulative use of pure reason.  This is what I'm getting:

Understanding, which is the categorical application of reason, allows for the synthesis of objects, while pure reason grounds the categorical application in what is logically possible.

Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: [SEP gives](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-reason/#ReaSci) the following surmise:"*For Kant, the “constitutive” use of our faculties helps to constitute the objects of knowledge, by providing their form as objects of possible experience... Regulative principles, by contrast, govern our theoretical activities but offer no (constitutive) guarantees about the objects under investigation.*" The first part is similar to yours, but "regulative" is what we today would call methodological maxims. It is not that logically possible must conform, but rather we presume that to guide our studies.

Comment: From the title Kant obviously wanted to critique pure reason on his (transcendental) ground, thus it's incorrect understanding that from his POV *pure reason grounds the categorical application in what is logically possible*...

Comment: Thank you for responding Conifold, but Kant's own language contradicts SEP, "For through ideas, as we have shown, it [reason] is not capable of any synthetic judgments that would have objective validity; through concepts of the understanding, however, it certainly erects secure principles, but not directly from concepts, but rather always only indirectly through the relation of these concepts to something entirely contingent, namely possible experience."  (A737/B765)

Comment: Put another way, it seems like Kant is trying to distinguish between objective and logical possibility.

Comment: A671/B699, Kant talks of ideas acting as ground, "Thus I say the concept of a highest intelligence is a mere idea, i.e., its objective reality is not to consist in the fact that it relates straightway to an object . . . ; rather, it is only a schema, ordered in accordance with the conditions of the greatest unity of reason, for the concept of a thing in general, which serves only to preserve the greatest systematic unity in the empirical use of our reason, in that one derives the object of experience, as it were, from the imagined object of this idea as its ground or cause."